# Magento 2.3.5 we found conflicting component dependencies

Tags: magento2, module, composer, magento2.3.4, web-setup-wizard

I have tried every possible solution I could find on the internet.

From increasing the MEMLIMIT in the php.ini to 2G to removing the required tags in composer.json and so on.

This is a Vanilla install of CE 2.3.4 for the life of me I can not figure out what could be causing this.

I was actually trying to install the connector for Magento Store Manager and I figured it was an issue with the module but it does it with any extension.

Comment: What is the output when running composer update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already checked the Release Notes of 2.3.5? In the [Known Issues section](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-5-open-source.html#known-issues) it is stating the following:

> Issue: Magento 2.3.5 does not support upgrading using the Web Setup
>   Wizard from deployments running Magento 2.3.3 or earlier without first
>   manually updating dependencies for magento/updater. You can upgrade
>   using the Web Setup Wizard without issue from Magento 2.3.4 to Magento
>   2.3.5. Workaround: Users should run the following commands before upgrading using the Web Setup Wizard:
>
> cd update
>
> && composer update

Comment: I performed a vanilla installation of 2.3.5 and it still gives the error.  Trying the composer update command.  I will return with an update

Comment: I did the composer update and now the site doesn't work at all

Comment: @Tommy make sure you run all the follow up to the update, wipe all caches,  bin/magento setup:upgrade etc

Comment: This is the part I am lost at.  Either that or I have been looking at this way to long.  Could you please list  the commands?  i.e. the follow up to the update?

Comment: I ran these commands and I am still getting the dependency check error.  This is a vanilla install, so could someone go in and check it for me?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check you PHP Version ? (`php -v`).

According to dev docs :

```
Supported PHP versions:

~7.2.0

~7.3.0
```

According to my experience, you should never use the last PHP version : the penultimate is always more stable than the last, so try PHP ~7.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a stab in the dark but I have had strange issues in my installation until I started running composer starting with a call to a PHP executable and passing a memory limit.

In my case:

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php72 -d memory_limit=3G  [full path to your composer executable]
```

Alas I haven't figured out how to edit the magento configs so the internal composer it calls now and then (eg: module:uninstall) also does the same so a few things still hang and need manual follow up

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Not sure it’s a fix, but I was finally able to figure out how to install modules via composer.  I did it by accident, but inevitably it worked.  Thank you for all the help everyone.